# Select Min value from a group without first row

Tags: mysql, min

Hello I want one query with one objective...

Select the min value from a field for example:

```
id  |   row    |  value
-----------------------
 8  |    1     |  0.9 
 7  |    1     |  0.8
 6  |    1     |  0.7
 5  |    1     |  0.6
 4  |    2     |  0.5
 3  |    2     |  0.4
 2  |    3     |  0.3
 1  |    1     |  0.2
```

I need to select the min value from this table where row = '1' in this case is id = 1 right? BUT I don't want the id = 1, I want only the min value from the first continuos row, in this case is the id = 5 because row = '1' have the id 8, 7, 6, 5, and the min value is 0.6, the id = 5.

What query I need?

Comment: What do you mean "only the min value from the first continuous row"?

Comment: the continuous row have the number 1 id 8, 7, 6, 5, I need the min value from that continuous row, because the number 1 is in id = 1 too, but is not continuous, because the number 3 is after

Comment: So what if id 5 => 0.7 and id 6 = 0.6

Comment: Hi wearedoom, could you try to edit your question and clarify a bit more? Also make the question more readable, because it's not clear what you are asking here. Specifically the continuous row specification isn't clear at all.

Comment: So, 8 isn't continuous either, because it has nothing after :-$

Comment: Is possible to have few sequences of row (i.e. ids 13, 14 and 15 have row =1) with value could be but not necesserally less than 0.6?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're after this, but it's very hard to tell...

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.id = x.id + 1 
   AND y.row = x.row 
 WHERE x.row = 1 
 ORDER 
    BY x.value 
 LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
SELECT min(value), id
WHERE value > (SELECT min(value)
               FROM MyTable
               WHERE row = 1)
AND row = 1
GROUP BY id;
```

Inner query will find min value for row as 1 while outer query will find next min value that is greater than min value we got in inner query.

Comment: Syntax errors aside, if I understand the OP's request correctly (and I'm not certain that I do) then this query is only correct by coincidence.